# Change html in iframe using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, html-table

How can I change the width of these tables to 1000px in an iframe using jquery?

```
<iframe>
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <table width="700">Data</table>
      <table width="700">Data</table>
      <table width="700">Data</table>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: cannot be done within different domains, see Same origin policy

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke jQuerys [`.contents()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('table').attr('width', '1000px');
```